# Assign a class based on matching text

Tags: angular

I have a list of albums as an array in my component ts. In my HTML I display each of the albums using an ngFor. Each of these items have a default class of "album_item"

After a query, I have a service that returns the name of an album. If the returned album name from the service matches one of the album names in the components albums array, I want to add a 'highlighted' class to show which album has matched (such as "album_item_highlight")

So far I have my html display the list of albums from the array, I have the correct default class showing and I can correctly return an album from a service.

I'd appreciate help with assigning another class when an item matches.

```ts
export class AlbumsComponent implements OnInit {

  albums = ["Album One", "Album Two", "Album Three"];

  returnedAlbum: string;

  matchingAlbum = true;

  constructor(
    public albumsService: AlbumsService,
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    // My service is returning one album and storing it as 'myAlbum'
    this.returnedAlbum = this.ablumsService.myAlbum;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="album-wrapper">
  <div class="label">Albums</div>
  <div *ngFor="let album of albums">
    <div class="album_item" [class.selectedAlbum]="matchingAlbum"> {{ album }} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding? Tried to implement anything? What happened?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have, and I've updated my question. But the area I'm stuck on still stands as highlighted in the question. I'm not entirely sure how to match the returned item to an item in the array and only apply that class to the correct html item. (Also, as a kind note, thank you for reformatting my question to make it harder to read.. :P - I think if more mods spent time helping people instead of unnecessarily formatting questions and down voting, most people would be progressing far quicker..especially when the question was formatted cleanly and concisely.)

Comment: So what's `matchingAlbum` supposed to be? Is that related to `matchingTheme`? Do you get errors? Unexpected outputs? If you want to apply to a specific item have you considered *using that item*, or its index? This isn't a tutorial service, it's not for general "help"; give a clear [mcve] of a specific problem. And I disagree with your premise that a question full of headings and lists is somehow easier to read, not to mention that it's at all worthwhile to repeat the technology in the tags, the title *and* the body or to say you're trying to articulate it (who isn't?)

Comment: I've updated the code. matchingTheme is actually matchingAlbum. As you'd expect with this approach, the class is applied to all items because it's naturally set to true. I need assistance with the logic to match the returned item to one in the array. That's what I need help with. Segregating the concerns of the questions into specifics is far clearer. It certainly didn't deserve a down vote and rewrite into a block of text. I'll be sure to reformat any future questions differently to meet your personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using the following approach (which seemed easier than looking through an index)

**Component TS**

```
this.matchingAlbum = this.albumService.mySettings_album;
```

**Component HTML**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'activeAlbum': album===matchingAlbum, 'defaultLabel': album !=matchingAlbum}"> {{ album }} </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `[ngClass]`:

```
[ngClass]="{'someOtherClass': matchingAlbum}"
```

Doc Ref:  https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass